# Spotify Web API: Track playable in the US even though US is not in available_markets

Tags: spotify

When using the Spotify Web API to search for tracks, one of the returned keys is available_markets. For example, the following query returns 2 tracks:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=maneater&type=track&limit=2

First track's available_markets: [
"AD",
"AR",
"AT",
"AU",
"BE",
"BG",
"BO",
"BR",
"CA",
"CH",
"CL",
"CO",
"CR",
"CY",
"CZ",
"DE",
"DK",
"DO",
"EC",
"EE",
"ES",
"FI",
"FR",
"GB",
"GR",
"GT",
"HN",
"HU",
"IE",
"IS",
"IT",
"LI",
"LT",
"LU",
"LV",
"MC",
"MT",
"MX",
"NI",
"NL",
"NO",
"NZ",
"PA",
"PE",
"PL",
"PT",
"PY",
"RO",
"SE",
"SI",
"SK",
"SV",
"TR",
"UY"
],

Second track's available markets: [
"AR",
"AT",
"AU",
"BE",
"BG",
"CH",
"CO",
"CZ",
"DE",
"DK",
"EE",
"ES",
"FI",
"FR",
"GR",
"HU",
"IE",
"IS",
"IT",
"LT",
"LV",
"NL",
"NO",
"NZ",
"PL",
"PT",
"RO",
"SE",
"SG",
"SK"
]

The first track (spotify:track:6mwZS6fLcQP1wKv3HN3OcY) can be played by a US account, the second (spotify:track:6k2ENY71MpS2TI0yFWHioo) cannot.

I was anticipating that 'US' would appear in the available_markets for the US-playable track, but it does not. The obvious difference between the two is that the first track is available in 54 markets and the second only 30.

How can you tell if the track can be played by a US account if the US is not listed in available_markets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to play a track in the Desktop client and it isn't available in your country, the client will look for *similar* tracks, e.g. the same track but from a different release of the same album, that it can play instead. This logic isn't exposed in the Web API.

So while it is true that this particular track URI isn't playable in the US, another one is, which is likely to be in the search results as well (spotify:track:4xw1S4UaU7cLYtkkDY59SN for example).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I increased the query limit from 2 to 30 and was able to find similar tracks with "US" in available_markets.